# Toggle button in Excel Online

Tags: excel, vba

What I can use except button in online Excel? It's not allowed:

> We can't show these features in the browser:
>
> • Objects like form toolbar controls, toolbox controls, and ActiveX
>   controls But you can see all the content in this workbook by opening
>   the file in Excel.

I just wanted to give end user solution for hidding/showing many group of columns.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "L:P"
If ToggleButton1.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CheckBox.

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
```

Comment: I changed button and code and I got error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251554(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: And check boxes also aren't allowed https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-check-box-in-Excel-Online-EE90CCF4-AD25-4EFD-9855-F5B062C3F664